# How to upload a shapefile to geoserver using cURL?

Tags: python, geoserver, windows

I need to automatically (using python) upload a shapefile into my geoserver.

I'm trying to do as described in [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/rest-config-examples-curl.html#uploading-a-shapefile) but i'm getting this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Wrong magic number, expected 9994, got 1347093252* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I'm sending this:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H 'Content-type: application/zip' --data-binary @C:/x/test_data/localfile.zip http://localhost:8081/geoserver/rest/workspaces/test_VN/datastores/maisum/file.shp
```

Comment: what is the actual request you are sending?

Comment: iant, check my edit in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you're using Windows? Could you try using double quotes instead of single quotes?

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip" \
    --data-binary @C:/x/test_data/localfile.zip \   
    http://localhost:8081/geoserver/rest/workspaces/test_VN/datastores/maisum/file.shp
```

I think the problem is that Windows is ignoring the Content type as it's enclosed in single quotes. Therefore, Geoserver does not treat the file as zip. From the [Windows command shell documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx):

> ... any argument that contains spaces or begins or ends with
>   spaces must be enclosed in double quotes. This is particularly
>   important when using long file and directory names, which frequently
>   contain one or more spaces. If a double-quoted argument itself
>   contains a double quote character, the double quote must be doubled.
>   For example, enter "Quoted" Argument as """Quoted"" Argumen

---

Found this at the [Geoserver mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/27010).

> Sometimes after repeated failed uploads some files can linger around
>   on the server that cause problems. Go to your GEOSERVER_DATA_DIRECTORY
>   and remove any lingering files from the "data" directory under it.
>   Then try again.

Hopefully, that should help solve your problem.

Comment: hmm, no luck. I still got the same problem.

Comment: Oh, what version of Geoserver are you using btw? And have you ever successfully uploaded a file or is this your first attempt?

Comment: I uploaded a lot of files but not programaticaly. first time with that. My geoserver is v2.2.2

Comment: Updated my answer. I think it's the quotes that did it.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Now I just need to be able to replace the previous file everytime I run this

Comment: Best to ask that one on another question so that everybody will benefit :)

Comment: done: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42357/how-to-upload-a-shapefile-to-geoserver-using-curl-and-replace-file

Answer (score 0):

even if the answer is already found i would like to point to an nice article about adding layers to Geoserver using curl for the users who are still searching for some more information about that: 
http://boundlessgeo.com/2012/10/adding-layers-to-geoserver-using-the-rest-api/