# Uploading shapefile to GeoServer using cURL and replace file?

Tags: python, geoserver, windows

In the sequence of this:

[How to upload a shapefile to geoserver using cURL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42309/how-to-upload-a-shapefile-to-geoserver-using-curl)

which was properly solved, I now need to be able to replace the existing file, cause my process is to be repeated every day.

Any clues?

Comment: How many files do you need to upload at any given day btw?

Comment: My process generates only one shp file a day, which I need to put on geoserver.

Comment: The same shapefile? I mean, you'll be overwriting the old one or will you be generating new ones with different file names?

Comment: I'll be overwriting the old one.

Answer (score 3):

While there is no 'replace' operation, I guess you can first delete the file and after that uploading the new one having the same name the old had.

In GeoServer's REST configuration API there are DELETE and PUT operations for data stores (http://goo.gl/8Fgej).